# climbing stairs the int limitation between two solutions

Tags: java, int, fibonacci

When working on leetcode 70 climbing stairs: You are climbing a stair case. It takes n steps to reach to the top.Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?
Here is my first solution:

```
class Solution {

    public int fib (int n){
        if (n <= 2) return n;
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    public int climbStairs(int n) {
        return fib (n+1);

    }
}
```

when n <44, it works, but n >=44, it doesn't work.because of this, it leads to the failure in submission in leetcode.
but when use the 2nd solution, shows below

```
class Solution {
    public int climbStairs(int n) {
        if (n <= 2) return n;
        int[] allWays = new int[n];
        allWays[0] = 1;
        allWays[1] = 2;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
            allWays[i] = allWays[i-1] + allWays[i-2];
        }
        return allWays[n-1];
    }
}
```

the second solution is accepted by leetcode. however, when n >=46, it gives a negative number.

Can anyone give me some explanation why the first solution fails? what's the difference between the two solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Your first solution fails because it times out (the time taken is exponential)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException

Answer (score 0):

To understand the solution you need to understand the concept of `Dynamic Programming` and `Recursion`

In the first solution to calculate the n-th Fibonacci number, your algorithm is

`fib(n)= fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)`

But the second solution is more optimized
This approach stores values in an array so that you don't have to calculate `fib(n)` every time.

Example:

```
fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)
       = (fib(3) + fib(2)) + (fib(2) + fib(1))
```

By first solution, you are calculating  fib(2) twice for n = 4.

By second solution you are storing fibonacci values in an array

Example:
for n =4,

first you calculate `fib(2) = fib(1)+fib(0) = 1`
then you calculate `f(3) = f(2)+f(1)`
We don't have to calculate `the  fib(2)` since it is already stored in the array.

[Check this link for more details](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct. The number of ways to reach the top indeed follows the fibonacci sequence.

The first solution computes the fibonacci numbers recursively (`fib(n) = fib(n - 1) + fib(n-2)`). To compute any value, the function needs to recursively call itself twice. Every function call takes up space in a region of memory called the stack. Whats probably happening is when n is too large, too many recursive calls are happening and the program runs out of space to execute more calls.

The second solution uses Dynamic programming and memoization. This effectively saves space and computation time. If you don't know these topics, I would encourage you to read into them.

You are getting negative values since the 47th Fibonacci number is greater than the maximum value that can be represented by type `int`. You can try using `long` or the `BigInteger` class to represent larger values.

Answer (score 0):

for n = 44 no of ways = 1134903170
and for n = 45 no of ways = 1836311903

so for n = 46 number of ways will be **n=44 + n=45** *i.e 2971215073*

sign INTEGER can only store upto 2147483647 *i.e. 2^31 - 1*

Because of with for n=46 it is showing -ve number